# How to specify in XSD that an attribute must be a valid Class?

Tags: android, xml, xsd

I am trying to force an attribute in my XSD file to match a valid Class for an Android project.

I want to do something like:

```
<xs:element name="model">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="parentClass" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="childClass" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

What should I use instead of `xs:string`?

Comment: Do you mean, (a) it must be a valid Java class name, or (b) it must be the name of a class that actually exists? You can (probably) do (a) by defining a pattern facet. You can't do (b) - XSD doesn't have the ability to check your XML instance against external information.

Comment: I mean option b. Thanks for che clarification